# Build nk2 Outlook from Contacts Address Book

Tags: outlook

Clearing the nk2 cache is straightforward. However, I was wondering if anyone had had any success building a nk2 file with the contacts in the Contacts list. My original idea was to clear out the contacts that were not in my Address Book, so delete the nk2 file and then rebuild one from the Address book, or delete from the nk2 those that are not in my Address Book.

Essentially, does anyone know how to, in script or a nk2 editor, read the contents of the Address Book?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two URL's above no longer seem to be valid, so an old standby would be a good approach: [NK2View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_autocomplete.html). It's scriptable via the command-line. For example, to delete all emails of nirsoft.net domain:

```
/delete_contains "@nirsoft.net"
```

Or use its free for personal use sister app, [NK2 Editor](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html). Its [command line interface](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nk2edit_command_line_options.html) (more details [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/edit_nk2_script.html)) options are far more extensive. This particular command should work for you:

```
/generate_new_nk2 <Destination NK2 File> <Number Of Days> <Max Emails> <Sent Messages> <Received Messages>
```

Answer (score 3):

That worked great for me also and it is FREE!

http://www.outlooktip.com/install-outlook-nk2-autocache/

It was able to rebuild my NK2 from Sent and from select folders, I would NOT run this on inbox because it would autocomplete every email address.

Use:
- sent
- select folders